# Automatic distinction between PC-USB and Wall Adapter-USB

Tags: batteries, usb, wall-wart

I want to ask if it's possible and an advice on how to make an automatic distinction between an PC-USB port and Wall-USB adapter. I've a battery charger IC (for example http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/bq24074-556796.pdf) where I can set max. IN current. I have no problems to set it to 500mA, but I'll always charge the battery at 500mA in PC and Wall-Adapter. But I want to charge the battery at 1-1.5A when I connect it to Wall-Adapter and when I connect it to a PC I don't want to fry PC usb port and charge battery at 500mA. Something like in a smartphone. I thought about sending some data via usb to know if it's an PC or Adapter but I need something more safety and always working.

Comment: You can't check for a short between D+ and D- like everyone else?

Comment: You can get ICs which do all of the detection for you and then switch the USB D+/D- lines through to the rest of your device. MAX14578 is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways that USB high current is indicated (Apple's way and everyone else.)

Apple uses a resistor divider to set D+ and D- at various voltages to indicate between 500mA and near 2A charge.  1.1 and 1.5A I think in there.  I would have to think if this puts a kink to below if you use an Apple charger.

Everyone else shorts D+ and D- together.  Many USB charge controllers handle the detection on the USB data lines.  If you are making a one of device, that is an easier route.

For your own detection, tie D+ to VCC with 10k resistor.  Tie D- to GND with 100k resistor.  Read D-, if high you can pull high current.  If low, you can't.

For your Mouser linked chip: Pull EN2 low with 10k resistor.  Connect D- to EN1 to enable full current if data lines shorted or 100mA if not.

Comment: The Apple chargers use 50k ~ 75k resistors to pull the datalines to 2V ~ 3V depending on current and series, in most cases that I remember. So a 100k pull-down might not have a high enough EN voltage any more. The chip does also say it has a 285kOhm pull-down to GND close to where it says to always connect them, so... bit confusing there.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at using a common charger, rather than Apple's own standard.

Comment: I was just making the point, because the OP names no brands at all. But it'll work for most, if not all non-Apples that I know of.